# Date comaprison in python attribute error

Tags: python, datetime, attributeerror, strptime

I have a date stored in a text file in this format `"19 May 2021"`, I want to compare this date to the today's date to see if we have reached this date or not (> / <) comparisons. I was instructed to first convert this string date to a date object, I am failing to do so.

For overdue_tasks in task_overview:

```
# Iterating through the file
from datetime import date as dt

overdue_tasks = overdue_tasks.split(", ")
dates = overdue_tasks[4] # This date is found in this index
date_obj = dt.strptime(dates, "%d %b %Y")
print(date_obj) # Trying to see if the date did convert
```

This is the error I get:

```
line 27, in <module>
date_obj = dt.strptime(dates, "%m %d %y")
AttributeError:
type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Comment: `from datetime import datetime as dt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strptime()` method is from `datetime.datetime`, not `datetime.time`. See the documentation for [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

So you'll simply need to change

```
from datetime import date as dt
```

to

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Comment: Ok, I just did and i get these errors now: line 27, in <module>
    date_obj = dt.strptime(dates, "%m %d %y") ,   line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format),   line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '20 Oct 2019' does not match format '%m %d %y'

Comment: @snlonline You got the month and day swapped in the format.

Comment: @snlonline Also, the `%y` should be `%Y`.

Comment: @snlonline Finally, the month should be `%b`.

Comment: @snlonline Try using the format `"%d %b %Y"`.

Comment: Yes finaly it worked, Thank you so much, so now if i get the current date it should be also in this format?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

_your_date = "19 May 2021"

# your date
date_obj = dt.strptime(_your_date, "%d %b %Y")
now_date_obj = dt.now()


if date_obj < now_date_obj:    
    #TO DO
    print('reached')

else:
    #TO DO
    print('not reached')
```